# Fungus and splitting or rotting on palm trees

Tags: fungus, palm

There's some fungus growing on my palm trees as well as some splitting / rot. What is going on and how do I resolve this? I am in central Florida.

[image: fungus]

[image: palm tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a young Roystonea, a Royal Palm. It has certainly suffered some kind of blow or squeeze in the remoter past, however it looks reasonably dry. One suggestion would be to take a thin probe and test the density of the wounded area by gently pushing the probe into the wounded area. First test an area that is not wounded to get a feel for how resistant the tissues should be and then compare to the area of concern. If it feels soft and particularly if it weeps after the probing then you might be best off to replace the palm while it is still manageable. Otherwise if it feels solid then leave well alone; the crown looks reasonably healthy so let's think positive on this one.

Comment: I agree, just as likely that it is physical damage as a disease

Comment: Thanks, it has been this way for at least 6 months and it's not getting any worse.